# using python lxml+xpath to get videos from a page, get a list but can't print out the result?

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

Newbie for python, would like use lxml+xpath to get video link from web page, what I have now is:

```
import urllib2
from lxml import etree

url=u"http://hkdramas.se/fashion-war-%E6%BD%AE%E6%B5%81%E6%95%99%E4%B8%BB-episode-20/"
xpath=u"//script[contains(.,'label:\"360p\"')]"

html=urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
selector=etree.HTML(html)
get=selector.xpath(xpath)

print get
```

I've checke `type()` of `get`, which shows me it's a `list`, but when I `print get`, it shows me unexpected `[<Element script at 0x2a34b88>]`, what's that mean? and how can I extract the actually url of the video instead of `Element script`?

---

finally, I got why I had this problem, thanks @unutbu

```
xpath=u"//script[contains(.,'label:\"360p\"')]"
```

should be

```
xpath=u"//script[contains(.,'label:\"360p\"')]//text()"
```

which added `text()` to make sure return only text, but not elements,  under the selection element, notice the `//`, that for compatible when there are many sub-elements of the selection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`selector.xpath(xpath)` returns a list of tags (or more accurately, `Element`s). When you print a list of objects, Python shows the `repr` of those `Element`s. `<Element script at 0x2a34b88>` is the `repr` of the `script` `Element`.

If `elt` is the `script` `Element`, then
`elt.text` will return the text inside the `<script>` tag, but you'll need to use something else (besides lxml) to extract the url from the text. You could, for example, use the regex pattern `r'"(http[^"]+)"'` to search for text which begins with `"http` and continues until another double quote, `"`, is found:

```
import re
import lxml.html as LH

url = u"http://hkdramas.se/fashion-war-%E6%BD%AE%E6%B5%81%E6%95%99%E4%B8%BB-episode-20/"
xpath = u"""//script[contains(.,'label:"360p"')]"""
root = LH.parse(url)
for elt in root.xpath(xpath):
    for url in re.findall(r'"(http[^"]+)"', elt.text):
        print(url)
```

yields

```
http://hkdramas.se/wp-content/plugins/BSplugin-version-1.2/lib/grab.php?link1=NS71jbj8NVNANTN7N0Nq7Y7FjeN0NojTN47HNcN77_Nhjh7INm7ONLNijCNc7-7UN_NXNCjcNYjeNwNF7uNQNA7dNvNm7-Nr7vNW7-NtjN72N4jVNCN8NfN-NANm7l7rNP7ff5aa877861da31d8cc9dd087d6ce2417fb1308a676a771b787adbffbaa4a0bffNfNHjtj-N6NDNg7HjLND7F7fjMj.jVjKN1N-jMj7NXj7jNNyjTNwjgjmji7INANtNONsN2NvN6jMNaNTNdNlNON8j7N~NEjO7lNyN.jQNaNuN1NYNjjzNnNENUNmNm7Z707dNaNTNFN0N6N8N.NRNuN_7dNtjhjJN-jmNZNpjjNo7fNHjTNNNSNLjMNqNUjN7IN7NPNfNENKN3jT7dNs&link2=
http://hkdramas.se/wp-content/plugins/BSplugin-version-1.2/lib/grab.php?link1=NvNeNVN4N276Nz7JNSjz7lNLNvNV7Ij3Nx7FNn7.Ni7FNU76NDNMN.NqNkNo7QNKNINiNhjPNJjmNKjPNGN.No7B7BNC7Y7B7B7lN67tjb7JNJNT7rNANrNBN7N6Nt7lN1ND0ba06b7bac4bab5fbb42dbff6c27647ea71b4f725a0c73f175eadf3b459424edN0NBNvNZj77wNL7Wj_j_71NnN0jpNfjPNqNvjDN.jEN4NRNDjijejmjXNINqNijEjENKNfNdN3jiNDNOjcNyN4NwNzN4NqNlNqNAjDNQNBN0Nk7a7Rj8NXN_NiN6NFNmNmNLNwNm7YN7j77vNfNpNljw7HjENRjmNMjVNLNEjq7BN0NON57JNyNyjpN8Nbjz7lN-NfNYNMN.7IjD7.NQ&link2=
```

Note that you do not need to import `urllib2`. You can pass a url directly to `LH.parse`.

---

To get only the url which is followed by the string `'360p'`, you could use

```
for url in re.findall(r'"(http[^"]+).*360p"', elt.text):
    print(url)
```

Comment: thanks for quick and detailed reply, though I am not familiar of `re` module, I think I can catch up later for this. But the part of explanation of xpath is  very useful, thanks. I will put my solution on OP.